Natural map of automorphism groups
Question: Write $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{\infty}) = \mathbb{Q}(E)$, where $E$ is the group of roots of unity in $\mathbb{Q}^{*}$. Prove that $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{\infty})$ is Galois, and that the natural map $\text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{\infty}) / \mathbb{Q}) \rightarrow \text{Aut}(E) \cong \hat{\mathbb{Z}}^{*}$ is an isomorphism of topological groups.
Own attempts: I think I managed to show that $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{\infty})$ is Galois by considering the collection of subfields
$I = \{\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{n}) : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$.
Since we have that $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{\infty}) = \bigcup_{L \in I} L$, and the fact that $L/\mathbb{Q}$ is finite Galois for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ it follows that $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{\infty})$ is Galois.
I am mainly confused about the second part of the question, in particular defining the map
$\phi : \text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{\infty}) / \mathbb{Q}) \rightarrow \text{Aut}(E)$.
What is this map explicitly given by? I know that the automorphisms in $\text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{\infty}) / \mathbb{Q})$ are fully determined by their action on the roots of unity $\zeta_{n}$, and that each $\zeta_{n}$ can be mapped to $\zeta_{n}^{k}$ where $k \in (\mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z})^{*}$. But wouldn't this automorphism be mapped to itself under the map $\phi$? If anyone can help me out with this part I would gladly appreciate that.

$E$ is a subgroup of the multiplicative group (the torsion subgroup) and is invariant under every field automorphism. The natural map is therefore given by just restricting the automorphisms to $E$.

Thank you for your comment @TimSeifert. I have a question, if I want to for example show that $\phi$ defined as the restriction is a morphism of groups I need to show that $(\sigma \circ \tau)\mid_{E} = \sigma\mid_{E} \circ \tau\mid_{E}$. Then is it correct that this just follows since the restrictions $\sigma\mid_{E}(\zeta_{n})$ acting on a root of unity is already given by how it is mapped by $\sigma \in \text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{\infty}) / \mathbb{Q})$, i.e. that $\sigma(\zeta_{n}) = \zeta_{n}^{k}$ for $k \in (\mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z})^{*}$.

Restriction means that you apply exactly the same function, just on a subset. So there really is nothing to check (apart from verifying that $E$ is invariant) as both group operations are (literally) the same thing.

Got it. Thanks a lot.
